# Dockerfile after build container doesn't work ''Could not find or load main class''

Tags: java, docker

**Yoo Coders!**
have one issue with docker, when i create container and after build it,i want run him,but have this **Error**

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Go
2022-02-18T19:52:59.856728094Z Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Go
```

** class  Go**

```
package sk.wynny;

public class Go {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("YOOOO bro!");
    }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:17.0.1
RUN mkdir /app

COPY out/production/ /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD  java Go
```

[image]

Comment: Your main class is `sk.wynny.Go`, and you need to include that complete package name in the `java` command.  The same should be true if you run `java` from your host environment without involving Docker.

Comment: Can u try it with my project without any changes? my https://github.com/Wynnyy/DockerProblem.git , if for u will be working, so problem is on other side..

Answer (score 0):

The fully qualified name of your class is `sk.wynny.Go` and to run, you need to tell Java what is the current directory or your class with the `--classpath` option.

```
FROM openjdk:17.0.1
RUN mkdir /app

COPY out/production/ /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD  java -classpath /app sk.wynny.Go
```